# creating a service which holds values to be updated later with separate controllers

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a service which holds values that I want to be able to update from other controllers. It's a fake financial tracker which allows me to update the values in this service. I can't get it to work and I know I may be setting it up incorrectly. Can someone help me out with this?

My code:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    var Bkbank = angular.module('Bkbank' []);

    Bkbank.controller('dashboardCtlr', function ($scope, dashboardSrvs) {

        /*User Data*/
        $scope.userName = dashboardSrvs.userName;
        $scope.acctNum = dashboardSrvs.acctNum;
        $scope.startDate = dashboardSrvs.startDate;
        $scope.checkingsTotal = dashboardSrvs.checkingsTotal;
        $scope.savingsTotal = dashboardSrvs.savingsTotal;
        $scope.investTotal = dashboardSrvs.investTotal;
        $scope.ouncesUpdate = dashboardSrvs.ouncesUpdate;
        $scope.debtBalance = dashboardSrvs.debtBalance;
        $scope.goldSpot = dashboardSrvs.goldSpot;

        /*Section Titles*/
        $scope.userTitle = dashboardSrvs.userTitle;
        $scope.servicesTitle = dashboardSrvs.servicesTitle;
        $scope.checkingsTitle = dashboardSrvs.checkingsTitle;
        $scope.savingsTitle = dashboardSrvs.savingsTitle;
        $scope.investTitle = dashboardSrvs.investTitle;
        $scope.debtTitle = dashboardSrvs.debtTitle;
        $scope.savingsUpdateTitle = dashboardSrvs.savingsUpdateTitle;


    });


    Bkbank.service('dashboardSrvs', function () {

        /*User Data*/
        this.userName = "Tim Willson";
        this.acctNum = 554887;
        this.startDate = "01/12/75";
        this.checkingsTotal = "56458.00";
        this.savingsTotal = "98187.00";
        this.investTotal = "34143.00";
        this.ouncesUpdate = "30";
        this.debtBalance = "10000.00";
        this.goldSpot = "1138.10";

        /*Section Titles*/
        this.userTitle = "User";
        this.servicesTitle = "Financial Services";
        this.checkingsTitle = "Checkings";
        this.savingsTitle = "Savings";
        this.investTitle = "Investments";
        this.debtTitle = "debt";
        this.savingsUpdateTitle = "Update Savings Account";

    });

}());
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what this does and doesn't do, and if there is a specific *technical thing* you want to know

Comment: your service isn't returning anything, not even itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully clear with the question you have asked but what I understood is you want to get/set attribute values into service so that updates available to all the consumer controller(s). In such scenario you can create service as e.g.

```
app.service('dashboardSrvs', function() {
  var userName = "Tim Willson"; //Set some default Value

  return {
    get userName() {
      return userName;
    },
    set userName(val) {
      userName = val;
    }
  }
});
```

And inside the controller you can update the userName as -

```
testService.userName = 'Mike Tyson';
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular merge to the rescue!

I advise you in advance to read this great article about Angular copy / extend / merge objects. Article [link here](http://davidcai.github.io/blog/posts/copy-vs-extend-vs-merge/)

```
var demoApp = angular.module("demoApp", []);


demoApp.service("dashboardService", function () {

    var configObj = {
        "userData": {
            "userName": "A",
            "acctNum": "B",
            "startDate": "C"
        }
    };

    return configObj;

});

demoApp.controller("appController", function ($scope, dashboardService) {

    // Override the new values of the service with a new object
    var newConfigValues = {
        "userData": {
            "userName": "X",
            "acctNum": "Z"
        }
    };

    var newConfigObj =  angular.merge({}, dashboardService, newConfigValues);

    console.log(newConfigObj); // "userName": "X", "acctNum": "Z", "startDate": "C"

});
```

As you can see, you can override all or just some values. If you do the latter, the original values in your service will be kept.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/teknotica/vxzw1khj/19/)